# Comparing a set of IP addresses against subnets using python and netaddr module

Tags: linux, python

Can I pass file in "ip_list" and "banned_subnets". I have multiple list of IP's which need to be get match with multiple subnets, and it is not possible to list them all in script. For that I have created two files `ipaddr_list` which has list of IP's and `sub_list` which has list of subnets.

Can some suggest how do I get this in below script:

```
import netaddr

ip_list = ['10.22.140.10', '10.11.14.11', '10.71.13.13', '10.10.131.2', '10.12.6.11', '10.1.6.10']

banned_subnets = ['10.1.6.0/24', '10.10.13.0/24', '10.10.14.0/24' ]

new_list = [str(ip) for ip in netaddr.IPSet(ip_list) & (netaddr.IPSet(banned_subnets))]

print new_list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm supposing that files you're saying you have for `ip_list` and `banned_subnets` are text files with each line containing an IP.

What you need to do is read those text file and strip them so they take form of list. I will add the code for one below you can accordingly use the code for another one.

```
with open('ip_list.txt') as f:
    IP_list = [line for line in f]
```

Hope you can do the same for `banned_subnets` as well.

Comment: It works but getting below error:

['10.11.10.100\n', '10.11.18.110\n', '10.71.131.123\n', '10.71.131.200\n', '10.11.6.11\n', '10.11.6.121\n', '10.11.6.11\n', '204.11.6.11\n', '\n']

['10.11.6.0/24\n', '10.71.131.0/24\n', '10.11.18.0/24_\n']


Below is the modified script:

#!/usr/bin/python
import netaddr



with open('ip_list.txt') as f:
    ip_list = [line for line in f]



with open('sub.txt') as p:
  banned_subnets = [line for line in p]

new_list = [str(ip) for ip in netaddr.IPSet(ip_list) & (netaddr.IPSet(banned_subnets))]

print new_list

Comment: So you can use this to form list:

`f = open('ip_list.txt' ,'r')
IP_list = (f.read()).split('\n')`

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list-with-python) here how to read line by line to list is given

Comment: This works for me. Is it possible to print unmatched ip's means can i print ip which is out of my subnet.

Comment: With this i may getting exact matches.
can some one help me to get ip's in output which is not in listed subnets. I want to find ip's which is not in my subnet.